# Why does factorial method always return the same result?

Tags: java, factorial

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Luke Mihalovich

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int n;

    System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
    n = keyboard.nextInt();

    int factorial = Factorial(n);   

    while (n >= 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);}

    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print(n = 1); }

    if (n == -1) {
        System.out.print("Goodbye!"); }
}

public static int Factorial(int n) {

    int factorial = 1;

    for(int i= 1;i<n;) {
        i++;
        factorial = factorial * i; }

    return factorial;
    }
}
```

This program prints the same result for all inputs.

For example, if I input `5`, the answer correctly is `5! = 120`. But if I enter `4`, it prints `4! = 120` again, which is wrong, it should be `24`.

Comment: try correct indenting, and probably you will see. You are reading the input variable and computing the result outside the `while`  loop.

Comment: @Renardo If you found the problem then please name it. The advice is always welcome, but don't withhold the solution if you know it.

Comment: You probably ought to think about how big a n has to be in order for n! to exceed the size of an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calculating the factorial after taking the input in the while loop instead what you are doing is calculating the factorial once before the while loop and that printing that every time a new input is given.

Update the main function as follows and it should work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=1;

    while (n >= 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter a non-negative integer (-1 to quit) : ");
        n = keyboard.nextInt();
        // Calculate the factorial for each number you take as the input
        int factorial = Factorial(n);
        System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);}

    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.print(n = 1); }

    if (n == -1) {
        System.out.print("Goodbye!"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

You wrote:

```
int factorial = Factorial(n);

while (n >= 1) {
    // ...
    System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);
}
```

**without updating** `factorial`. A statement like

```
int factorial = Factorial(n);
```

is only executed **once** and not live-linked such that it recomputes once you update `n`.

---

### Solution

So you will need to explicitly update `factorial` in each iteration:

```
int factorial = Factorial(n);

while (n >= 1) {
    // ...
    factorial = Factorial(n);
    System.out.println(n + "! = " + factorial);
}
```

---

### Notes

Please stick to **naming conventions**. Method names should always start with a **lower case** character, so it should be `factorial` instead. And the variable should then be re-named, to `result` for example.

Your *for-loop* looks strange. You may just use the usual notation and run to `<= n`, you can even skip `i = 1` and directly start at `i = 2`:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry, what? I don't see a mistake. To which part of the answer are you even referring to? Edit: Found it, edited. Next time, please be more concrete and specific.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you!

Comment: @LukeMihalovich You're welcome. Instead of leaving *thank you* comments you may consider **up-voting**, thanks.